# How to describe running npm script in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, npm, webpack

I described in Dockerfile the command to execute npm script:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/server
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

It's just a webpack script which build my project

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --mode development --open",
  "watch": "webpack --mode development --open --watch",
  "prod": "webpack --mode production"
},
```

During build i can see that command was executed:

```
Step 23/28 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app/server
 ---> Running in e85934faf65a
Removing intermediate container e85934faf65a
 ---> 9f14cb58deca
Step 24/28 : CMD [ "npm", "run", "build" ]
 ---> Running in 6d3157d2e962
Removing intermediate container 6d3157d2e962
 ---> 9237c0a03fe9
Step 25/28 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in 3888c83ed88f
```

I expect to get generated *dist* folder. But I can see that folder is not generated inside container

```
root@82a01ee6d1fe:/usr/src/app/server# ls
package-lock.json  package.json  src  tsconfig.json  webpack.config.js
```

How to execute npm script in Docker file correctly? 
What i did wrong?

Comment: Is the "dist" dir in your screenshot on the host machine and not in the container? Does that mean you're running the container with a volume mount?

Comment: Yes, on the screenshot it is not in container. I didn't mount a volume. I want to generate it inside container

Comment: Screenshots are not searchable and they don't make good questions or answers.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for your notice. Changed to text

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem using next command

```
RUN npm run build
```

That was really executed unlike `CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]`

And I had one problem with webpack. It didn't work from node_modules and i installed that globally:

```
RUN npm install -g webpack webpack-cli
```

Inside container i found *dist* folder and file *bundle.js* that generated by webpack:

```
root@49f66ba44ab9:/usr/src/app/server# ls
dist  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  src  tsconfig.json  webpack.config.js
root@49f66ba44ab9:/usr/src/app/server# ls ./dist
bundle.js
```